# Datatables in Laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, datatables

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to implement Datatables into my project but it doesn't seem to work.

My app.blade.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/af-2.2.2/b-1.5.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/af-2.2.2/b-1.5.1/datatables.min.css"/>
```

My view where my target table is:

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Liste des tickets   <a href="{{ url('/admin/tickets/export/xls')}}" class="btn btn-info">Exporter</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered" id="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Objet</td>
        <td>Urgence</td>
        <td>Statut</td>
        <td>Utilisateur</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      @foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->message}}</td>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->urgence->niveau}}</td>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->statut}}</td>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->utilisateur->name}}</td>
        <td style='white-space: nowrap'>
          <a href="{{ url('tickets/'.$ticket->id.'/voir')}}" class="btn btn-info">Voir</a>
          <a href="{{ url('tickets/'.$ticket->id.'/delete')}}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Êtes vous sûr de vouloir supprimmer ce ticket?')">Supprimer</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $tickets->render()}}
  </div>

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

Can you help me do so?

Edit : This is my TicketsController Code as required:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Tickets;
use Auth;
use Session;
use App\Gestion;
use Excel;
use App\assistance;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class TicketsController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
      $this->middleware('admin')->only('voir');
  }/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $urgences=DB::table('urgences')->pluck('niveau','id');
        $assistances=DB::table('assistances')->pluck('level','id');
        return view('tickets.creation',compact('urgences','assistances'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $data=$request->all();
      $this->validate($request,[
        'message'=>'required|min:8',
        'urgence_id'=>'required',
        'typeassistance'=>'required',
      ]);
      $data=array_add($data,'utilisateur_id',Auth::user()->id);

      Tickets::create($data);
      Session::flash('message','Vous avez ouvert un nouveau ticket.');
      return redirect('/home');

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function voir($id)
    {
      $gestions=Gestion::where('ticket_id',$id)->get();
      $assistances=DB::table('assistances')->pluck('level','id');
      $tickets=Tickets::findOrFail($id);
      if($tickets->statut=='nouveau'){
      $tickets->statut='ouvert';
      $tickets->save();
      }
      return view('tickets.show',compact('tickets','gestions','assistances'));
    }

    public function exportxls(){
    $weeklyTickets = \App\Tickets::whereBetween('created_at', array(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days")), date('Y-m-d')))->get();

    Excel::create('tickets', function($excel) use ($weeklyTickets){
      $excel->sheet('tickets', function($sheet) use ($weeklyTickets){
        $sheet->loadView('export.ticketsexcel', array('weeklyTickets' => $weeklyTickets));
      })->export('xls');
    });
    return redirect('/');
  }
  public function delete($id)
  {
    $tickets=Tickets::findOrFail($id);
    $tickets->delete();
    Session::flash('message','Vous avez bien supprimé le ticket.');
    return redirect('/');
  }
}
```

I would like my tables to be like the basic Datatables style, with the search bar. The search bar is a must for me, someone actually told me to use Datatables because i needed an instant search bar, I don't really mind the other parts of Datatables.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide details about what your problem actually is?

Comment: Move `<tbody>` tag above foreach loop.

Comment: my problem is that I followed the Getting started section of Datatables and it still doesn't apply to my table.

Comment: I moved <tbody> above foreach loop and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please use yajara datatable (https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

Comment: Using it,still doesn't work.

Comment: Hey Sam,
is there any error in console log?

Comment: No, no error, my table just doesn't look like the table on the Datatables exemple. Nothing changed to it.

Comment: can u show controller code

Comment: Which controller?

Comment: from where u are returning `$tickets`, show that controller code.

Comment: I edited the post with my TicketsController.

Comment: i cant see any code that specific to `yajra` in your controller. like `return DataTables::of($data)->make(true);`

Comment: Where should I add it then? Sorry If I seem lost.

Comment: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter, note `return Datatables::of(User::query())->make(true);`